# MySQL - importing a CSV file

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, csv, import

I am trying to import a large excel file containing text, values and links to websites etc into MySQL.

I have saved my .xlsx file as a .csv file and am trying to import it using the "table data import" tool. When I reach the screen where it asks for the encoding I am currently seeing all the correct column headings, but only five out of 15 of my rows. I think this must be due to an unrecogonized character being present in the 6th row. However, I do not know how to find what this character might be.

Also, if I select different encodings, then my 6th row appears but not the rest.

So, if anyone can help me to work out which characters are causing this error, I would be very grateful.

Thanks,

Sarah

Comment: It might help us if you post the first 2-3 rows of your file, formatted as code (indent each line by 4 spaces).  Also you should look into using `LOAD DATA`.

Comment: If you remove the 6th row, see how far it gets, then you can always add this line to your question and perhaps someone can help.

Comment: After removing some rows/columns and making lots of little changes, I have managed to import the full file. Thanks for your help!